# Compare array elements and add if not

Tags: arrays, bash, compare

I have a directory with two types of pictures. The name of photos starting with the year (e.q, 20131118SPECIFICNUMBER) and the name of drafts starting with swSPECIFICNUMBER.

I want to get an ls sw* into Array first:

```
    i=0
while read line
do
    array1[ $i ]="$line"        
    (( i++ ))
done < <(ls sw*)
```

Then I want to get an ls 20* into Array:

```
j=0
    while read line
    do
        array2[ $j ]="$line"        
        (( j++ ))
    done < <(ls 20*)
```

Last step is to compare the two Arrays and add a sw draft from array2 into array1 but is there already a image with compareable specific number I don't want to add the sw draft.

Example:

Array1[20131118ABC123, 20131118DEF456)
Array2[swABC123, swGHI789]

swGHI789 should be added to array1 but not swABC123 because there's already an image with the compareable specific number

I got an first idea but this is actually not what I need :(  pls help

```
for t in "${Array2[@]}"; do
     skip=
     for q not in "${Array1[@]}"; do
        [[ $t == $q ]] && { skip=1; break; }
     done
     [[ -n $skip ]] || Array1+=("$t")
 done
```

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this. `array1=( sw* )` and `array2=( 20* )` will populate your arrays with the desired set of file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use bash associated arrays for versions higher than 4.0 (I'm not sure if bash versions earlier than that would support this feature).

```
#!/bin/bash

# preparing the two arrays
array1=($(ls -1 20*))
array2=($(ls -1 sw*))

# create a dictionary
# key is specific number
# value is an integer greater than 0
value=1
declare -A dict  # declare an associated array
for elem in ${array1[@]}; do
    key=${elem:8}  # pick the specific number after date
    dict[$key]=$value
    value=$((value+1))
done

i=${#array1[@]}
for elem in ${array2[@]}; do
    key=${elem:2}  # pick the specific number after "sw"
    if [ -z "${dict[$key]}" ]; then
        array1[i]=$elem
        i=$((i+1))
    fi
done
```

Hope it helps.